# Do you know any matplotlib's colormap with distinguished colors to plot as many as 25 variables

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, ipython

I am using matplotlib to plot 25 variables but since I am using stacked bars it is difficult to distinguish the different variable from the graph because of similarities in colors. Is there a way to plot all these variables using stacked bars with distinguished color types.

This is the current code I am currently using.

```
df.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, fontsize=14, figsize=[16,42], colormap='hsv')
plt.title('plot title', fontsize=20, color='black') 
plt.xlabel('xlabel', fontsize=17, color='black') 
plt.ylabel('ylabel', fontsize=17, color='black')
```

I have tried a lot of colormap colors such as gist_ncar, inferno, viridis, hsv, prism, rainbow, gist_rainbow, etc., but all of them do not distinguish clearly all of the variables.

Do you know any colormap which has more color varities or any library which can do nicely this job.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Check here: http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html and here: http://matplotlib.org/api/cm_api.html and prolly here: http://matplotlib.org/cmocean/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have already tried most of these colors listed in the matplotlib documentation and unfortunatelly do not produce easy to understand visualizations in case of 20+ colors or so.

Comment: Another solution is to define the color of every  bar plot using html hex strings from here http://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp but its quite tedious

Comment: I think this is a misconception about how the human brain works. Although there are in principle infinitely many colors the brain will always categorize them, so I doubt there is a generic solution to this problem. You may want to look into other variables than color to make your bars appear distinct, like luminosity, saturation, structure, shape.

Comment: [Colorbrewer](http://colorbrewer2.org) tends to give reasonable advise on color schemes; you can get qualitative schemes [of up to 12 colors](http://colorbrewer2.org/#type=qualitative&scheme=Paired&n=12) there (although personally, I only find them easy to distinguish up to 10 colors) Perhaps combine that with e.g. hatching?